# To prevent the closing of bat file automatically

Tags: batch-file

while trying to run process the bat file terminates of its own.
How to stop the automatic closing of the bat file?

```
call C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat mvn package -Pdist,native-win,docs -DskipTests -Dtar
```

Comment: Add a pause command.

Comment: I have tried using pause command even then it terminates. Please tell me some more options to resolve it. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Show us your batch file. Edit it into your question by using the `edit` facility on the left-hand side opposite your signature.

Comment: call C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
 mvn package -Pdist,native-win,docs -DskipTests -Dtar

This is my batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" mvn package -Pdist,native-win,docs -DskipTests -Dtar
pause
```

You need to "quote pathnames containing spaces"

The `pause` will show the results.

The other two lines prevent the commands being `echo`ed to the screen and ensure the environment is kept clean. They are not *strictly* necessary.